# Fancybox - when reached last image slide to another five

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Screenshot

[image]

I use bootstrap 3 and fancybox, as you can see in screenshot I have 5 images in row and I want when reached last image to click on right arrow which will result slide to another five . Example with arrows

This is my code

```js
(function($) {

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        openEffect    : 'fade',
        closeEffect    : 'fade',
  loop : true
    });
});
})( jQuery );
```

```css
h2 {
 font-family: 'Sintony' sans-serif;
 font-size: 25.5px;
 color: #00aeef;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin: 0;
 padding-top: 42px;
 padding-bottom: 14px;
}

.fancybox img {
 margin-right: 4px;
 margin-bottom: 7px;
 border-radius: 8px;
 display: inline;
 }
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 illustrative">
    <h2>illustrative works</h2>
    <p>Sed suscipit risus vel sapien fringilla elementum. Donec vulputate sapien suscipit nulla tincidunt sodales. 
    Ut ut nisi in nisl convallis ultricies. Curabitur tristique faucibus tincidunt. 
    Donec rutrum mi faucibus nisi luctus sodales facilisis neque semper. </p>
    
    <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" data-fancybox-group="gallery1" href="http://www.linecase.mile.x3.rs/wp-content/themes/linecase/img/fabulous-Illustration-b.jpg" title="DJ Fabulous Illustration">
     <img src="http://www.linecase.mile.x3.rs/wp-content/themes/linecase/img/fabulous-Illustration-s.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="DJ Fabulous Illustration" />
    </a>
    <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" data-fancybox-group="gallery1" href="http://www.linecase.mile.x3.rs/wp-content/themes/linecase/img/card_b.jpg" title="Illustrative artwork for American recording artist Mike Posner's debut single 'Cooler than me">
     <img src="http://www.linecase.mile.x3.rs/wp-content/themes/linecase/img/card_s.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Illustrative artwork for American recording artist Mike Posner's debut single 'Cooler than me" />
    </a>
    <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" data-fancybox-group="gallery1" href="http://www.linecase.mile.x3.rs/wp-content/themes/linecase/img/Saskia-Pomeroy-Abstract-Colour-Shapes-Forms-b.jpg" title="Saskia Pomeroy Abstract Colour Shapes Forms">
     <img src="http://www.linecase.mile.x3.rs/wp-content/themes/linecase/img/Saskia-Pomeroy-Abstract-Colour-Shapes-Forms-s.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Saskia Pomeroy Abstract Colour Shapes Forms" />
    </a>
    <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" data-fancybox-group="gallery1" href="http://www.linecase.mile.x3.rs/wp-content/themes/linecase/img/illustration11_b.jpg" title="Just Another Illustration sample">
     <img src="http://www.linecase.mile.x3.rs/wp-content/themes/linecase/img/illustration11_s.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Just Another Illustration sample" />
    </a>
    <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" data-fancybox-group="gallery1" href="http://www.linecase.mile.x3.rs/wp-content/themes/linecase/img/city_b.jpg" title="Illustration City">
     <img src="http://www.linecase.mile.x3.rs/wp-content/themes/linecase/img/city_s.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Illustration City" />
    </a>
    
   </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, what you are looking for is a slider/carousel, where each slide contains a set of 5 images.
[Owl carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/) is a good option that I have used for several projects.

Comment: Ok, but how to implement slider/carousel in fancybox? I don't want to use Owl carousel right now.

Comment: Well, fancybox supports slideshow - but as in, it will transition between the gallery images. There is no easy way to implement a carousel in fancybox. I think the proper way to do it is with a dedicated carousel lib - and use fancybox as you already do, as a lightbox solution

Comment: flemcito I used Dynamic content via JSON, and it is superb. But how to open large image when click on thumbnail image in slider?

Comment: It's a bit hard to answer without the code, but can you not use fancybox for that as you did? (maybe fancybox needs to be initialized in a callback to work on dynamically loaded content)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the bootstrap carousel. here is the example [bootstrap carousel](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/responsive-moving-box-carousel)

Comment: yes I know for bootstrap carousel, but it is something completely different compared to what I want